# How to use block num in gvim, or backticks with italian keyboard?

Tags: windows, vim

I'm using gVim and italian keyboard (no backticks).

On windows the only way to type backticks is `block-num + alt + 96`, yes, very sad. More sad when you find that block num does not work on gvim :(

Can you tell me how to activate block num on gvim? or a fastest way to type beacktick on windows, in gvim as well?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your keyboard layout is the same as [that shown on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keyboard_layout#Italian), you could
map `` ` `` to `\`, and map `\` (if you use it as a leader key, for example) to,
say, `_` (which would be even easier to type than `\` in that layout).

```
:noremap \ `
:let g:mapleader = '_'
```

Comment: Do you mean use these statements in my .vimrc file?

Comment: @empo:  Yes, put these lines to your `.vimrc` file.  By the way you can try these changes interactively first (entering that commands in Vim command mode), and see whether the mappings are comfortable for you.

Comment: ok, thanks. I won't be able to try it interactively because I need to use block num :( to type the backtick. I will go with .vimrc directly.